# I want my loop to end at the given number in java

Tags: java

I want to key in a value(int) as a parameter and make a loop from zero until it reaches that number.

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

int m=0;
int a;
a=s.nextInt();
while(a<=10) {
    System.out.println(m); m++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

while loop must be like this:

```
while(m<=a) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In while condition you need to add m<=10 not a.